# Pregunta sobre metodos y clases en Javascript

Tags: javascript, clase

Mi pregunta es: Para llamar al metodo cliente y total no hace falta () ya que son metodos, pero porque a imprimir si me hace falta los parentesis? Si es porque es una funcion normal y corriente, porque no se le puede poner function delante?

```js
class Factura{ 
  constructor(numero, cliente, importe, IVA){
    this._numero = numero;
    this._cliente = cliente;
    this._importe = importe;
    this._IVA = IVA;
  }

  get cliente(){ // metodo get
    return this._cliente;
  }

  get total(){ // metodo get
    return this._importe + this._IVA;
  }

  
  imprimir(){ 
    document.write('la factura numero ' + this._numero + ' es de ' + this._cliente)
  }
}

let factura1 = new Factura(512, 'Transportes Miguelito', 100, 21); 

console.log(factura1._cliente);
console.log(factura1.total);
factura1.imprimir();
```

Comment: Los `métodos` son funciones y `cliente` y `total` no.

Answer (score 1):

Es justo al revés: para `imprimir` utilizas paréntesis porque es un método, en este caso sin argumentos aunque podría tenerlos.

Para `cliente` y `total` no utilizas paréntesis porque son propiedades y utilizas la sintaxis propia para asignar y recuperar valores de cualquier propiedad:

```
var valor = instancia.cliente;
```

o para establecer el valor:

```
instancia.cliente = valor;
```

en tu caso no se puede establecer el valor de estas propiedades porque únicamente tienen un método "getter" (`get`) pero no tienen método "setter" (`set`) para establecer el valor. Si lo tuviesen podrías hacerlo también:

```js
class Factura{ 
  constructor(numero, cliente, importe, IVA){
    this._numero = numero;
    this._cliente = cliente;
    this._importe = importe;
    this._IVA = IVA;
  }

  get cliente(){ // metodo get
    return this._cliente;
  }

  get total(){ // metodo get
    return this._importe + this._IVA;
  }

  
  imprimir(){ 
    console.log('la factura numero ' + this._numero + ' es de ' + this._cliente)
  }
}

let factura1 = new Factura(512, 'Transportes Miguelito', 100, 21); 

console.log('Cliente factura1 ', factura1.cliente);
console.log('Total factura1 ', factura1.total);
// No puedo establecer valor a propiedad cliente
factura1.cliente = 'Asier Villanueva';
console.log('Nuevo cliente factura1 ', factura1.cliente);
// Metodo sin argumentos
factura1.imprimir();

class Factura2{ 
  constructor(numero, cliente, importe, IVA){
    this._numero = numero;
    this._cliente = cliente;
    this._importe = importe;
    this._IVA = IVA;
  }

  get cliente(){ // metodo get
    return this._cliente;
  }
  
  set cliente(value){
    this._cliente = value;
  }

  get total(){ // metodo get
    return this._importe + this._IVA;
  }

  
  imprimir(saludo){ 
    console.log(saludo + '. La factura numero ' + this._numero + ' es de ' + this._cliente)
  }
}

let factura2 = new Factura2(512, 'Transportes Miguelito', 100, 21); 

console.log('Cliente factura2 ', factura2.cliente);
console.log('Total factura2 ', factura2.total);
// Sí puedo establecer valor a propiedad cliente
factura2.cliente = 'Asier Villanueva';
console.log('Nuevo cliente factura2 ', factura2.cliente);
// Método con argumentos
factura2.imprimir('Hola');
```

Tu problema creo que es más de nomenclatura. Igual se me echan encima por decir algunas inexactitudes pero voy a tratar de dejarlo claro a nivel general.

En javascript prácticamente todo se define con funciones: la definición de una clase no es más que un tipo especial de función, el constructor otro, un getter o setter de una propiedad se define mediante una función que establece o devuelve el valor de ésta,...

De hecho en alguna ocasión he oído definirlo como un lenguaje basado en funciones. Definición que personalmente me parece bastante acertada aunque podría suscitar un amplio debate.

Por otro lado los valores (los que asignamos a las variables) de javascript pueden ser de alguno de los tipos denominados como primitivos (boolean, Number, String,...) u objetos.

Los objetos (dejaremos el caso particular del Array a parte por ahora) pueden tener propiedades y métodos. Las propiedades son elementos de un tipo particular y que sirven para mantener el valor de una característica del objeto (en el caso de la factura: cliente, número de factura, proveedor, importe,...). La forma de asignar o recuperar los valores de estas propiedades/características del objeto sería:

```
 // Recuperar valor
 var miVariable = instanciaObjeto.nombrePropiedad;
 // Asignar valor
 instanciaObjeto.nombrePropiedad = nuevoValor;
```

Los métodos son diferentes acciones que se pueden ejecutar sobre el objeto. Estos métodos pueden recibir o no uno o varios argumentos, y pueden devolver o no un valor. Estos métodos pueden servir para modificar el estado interno del objeto (en la factura podría haber un método `añadirLineaFactura` que añadiese datos de una nueva línea: `factura1.añadirLineaFactura(datosNuevaLinea);`) o devolver un valor calculado (por ejemplo un método `calcularIVA`: `var importeIVA = factura1.calcularIVA();`).

Espero haber echado un poco de luz.

Comment: pero get es un metodo, un metodo que quiere traerse la propiedad cliente para almacenarla y ya? Intento ir mas alla y me lio mas de lo que deberia ya que pienso que si get es un metodo deberia usa () pero segun tu es una propiedad, se que get es un metodo, pero cliente es una propiedad, igual esa linea es una propiedad por eso no hace falta () ? Con entender eso me vale?

Comment: Voy a ampliar mi respuesta a ver si consigo aclarar un poco los términos